# Musixtex horizontal separation space for sixteenth note with stem up in Ten Stroke Roll Rudiment

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the Musixtex horizontal separation space for  sixteenth note with stem up in Ten Stroke Roll Rudiment as show in picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \largemusicsize
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    {\Huge{\textcircled{\large 11}}}$\quad$
    \Notes \trrrmu a\islurd0a\zcn{j}{\hspace*{-0.03cm}$10$}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}\qu a \tslur0a\usf g\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R \quad L}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L \quad R}\ibbu0a0\qb0{a}\tbu0\usf g\qb0{a}\lower3.5\Interligne\ds \en 
    \zendextract
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The code generates the following output:
[image: current output]

The desired output should be:

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... inside any pair `\notes...\en` there are two equivalent ways to
> locally redefine `\noteskip` to another scalable value, namely by
> issuing a command like `\noteskip=2.4\noteskip` or
> `\multnoteskip{2.4}`, which have the expected effect until the notes
> group is terminated or `\noteskip` is further redefined.

(musicxdoc, page #20}

Using `\noteskip=0.35\noteskip` in the example.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}
    
    \sffamily\bfseries
    
\begin{music}
    \largemusicsize
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    {\Huge{\textcircled{\large\normalfont 11}}}$\quad$
    \Notes\trrrmu a\islurd0a\zcn{j}{\hspace*{0.1cm}\normalfont\emph{10}}\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small R}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small L}\noteskip=1.4\noteskip\qu a\tslur0a\usf g\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small R\enspace L}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small L\enspace R}\ibbu0a0\noteskip=0.35\noteskip\qb0{a}\tbu0\usf g\qb0{a}\lower3.5\Interligne\ds\en%
    \zendextract%   
\end{music}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially when you type short lines, my solution, application musixlyr, could save you a lot of work:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{spanish}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
    
    \usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
    \usepackage{musicography}
    \usepackage{musixtex} 
    \input{musixlyr}
    \input {musixcho}
    \input {musixdat}%fecha
    \input {musixfll}
    \input {musixgre}%gregoriano
    \input {musixper}%percusión
    \input {musixppff}
    \input {musixstr}
    \input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
    \input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
    \input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
    \input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
        \largemusicsize
        \setlines{1}{0}%
        \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    

    \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule
    \setlyrics{R}{R R L}% added for hand indication
    \setlyrics{L}{L L R}% added for hand indication
        \startextract
        \A\assignlyrics1{R,L}% added to place handindication
       \Notes\charnote f{\Huge{\textcircled{\Large 11}}}\sk\en%$\quad$ lifted the number, \sk is the music way to skip one noteskip

            \Notes \trrrmu h\islurd0h\zcn{r}{\hspace*{-0.03cm}\it{10}}%

% note hight changed to h to stop need of lowering rests
            %\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L}%

            \qu h\sk\sk\sk\tslur0h\usf p%

% added three noteskips to make the quarter exactly four times the sixteenth
            %\zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} R \quad L}\zcharnote{-14}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} L \quad R}%

            \ibbu0h0\qb0{h}\tbu0\usf p\qb0{h}%

%\lower3.5\Interligne

            \ds \en 
            \zendextract
        \end{music}
        
        
        \end{document}
```

The only point is, I do not seem to have `musixvbm.tex'. Nevertheless, this is my result:[image: score]